# Apex Email Error - INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Invalid to address

Tags: apex, email

> SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Invalid to address : : [] Error is in
>   expression '{!sendEmail}' in component  in page 
>   MyPage: Class.MyClass.sendEmail: line 408, column 1

Send Email code is as below

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
message.saveAsActivity = false;
message.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(emailFromAddress);//emailFromAddress(string)-containing id
message.setCcAddresses(new String[]{emailCCAddress});//emailCCAddress(string)
message.setBccAddresses(new String[]{emailBCCAddress});//emailBCCAddress(string)
message.setSubject(emailSubject);//emailSubject(string)
message.setHtmlBody(emailBody);  //emailBody(string)
message.setToAddresses(new String[]{emailToAddress.trim()}); //emailToAddress is a string containing 'abc@abc.com'
//message.setToAddresses(new String[]{'abc@abc.com'}); //Tried this too still giving same error
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] mailResults = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{message});// Line 408 where error occurs
```

Please help! i am facing this issue since long time. Tia

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try validating cc and bcc addressess by checking null or empty

```
  if(emailCCAddress != null && emailCCAddress.trim() != ''){
        Ccaddress = emailCCAddress.split(',',0);
        mail.setCcAddresses(ccaddress);
        }
  if(emailBCCAddress != null && emailBCCAddress.trim() != ''){
        Bccaddress = emailBCCAddress.split(',',0);
        mail.setBccAddresses(Bccaddress);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by debugging this line, as it is likely causing the issue:

system.debug('EMAIL IS ' + new String[]{emailToAddress.trim()});

Then you can see if that is just not a valid email before you start to get crazy, most of the time it is something dumb that is holding you up, it is possible the value of 'emailToAddress' is not what you are expecting.

Comment: That was my first step of solving issue. It had shown a valid email address. Anyways thanks for your help. My BCC address had issue so Animesh answer worked well for me :)